# Do limsup and liminf exist only for oscillating sequences?

Tags: real-analysis

In many sites including wikipedia, limsup and liminf are defined using the pictures of oscillating sequences.

[image: limsup and liminf of a sequence]

So, is there only this type of sequence which can have limsup and liminf?

(Ok, this is reasonable that a sequence jumping up & down can have limsup and liminf,but . . .)

Answer (score 5):

A sequence has a finite limsup and liminf if and only if it is bounded.

On the other hand if it is unbounded upwards, its limsup will be $\infty$. (And similarly for downwards unbounded sequences).

Comment: Hi sir; yes it is implied that the sequence must be bounded. But limit means that the sequence is converging to some finite value. Limsup would mean then the **sequence of sup i.e. the upper bound point converges to a finite value which is the limsup**. But for a sequence of sup to exist, the sequence must have variable upper bound & that is possible in the oscillating sequence like in the pic.

Comment: @user36790: Nobody says the successive suprema have to be diferent. For example, $a_n=1-\frac1n$ has a perfectly good limsup of $1$, and $\sup\{a_n\mid n>k\}=1$ for all $k$.

Comment: I am not saying the successive suprema is different. But it is rather a monotonic sequence. I just want to know whether a sequence has variable suprema or not.

Comment: @user36790: I'm afraid I don't understand what it is you're asking, then.

Comment: Sir, I only want to know whether I am thinking right or not. I'm new in this topic. So, I only wanted to know whether it is possible for a sequence to have a variable suprema. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user36790: Your majesty, if the sequence depicted in your question is not an example of a sequence that "has variable suprema", then I have no idea what you mean by those words.

Answer (score 3):

$\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are generally first defined for bounded sequences so that the limit superior and the limit inferior become real numbers.

The picture above found in Wikipedia does not seem to depict a converging sequence. But it is bounded. The picture is used to highlight the fact that although the sequence oscillates and does not converge $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ still exist.

But when you define $\limsup$ and $\liminf$  for unbounded sequences as well by including symbols $\infty$ and $- \infty$ we come to the very useful fact that ***every*** sequence has both. So in that sense, No. This is not the only type of sequence that has a limit superior and a limit inferior. In fact, in a general sense any sequence does.

Comment: When does a limit come to picture? When there is a variable and it approaches closer to a finite value; the variable must change. So, doesn't it mean that the **sup** must be a variable for the existence of limsup? Not every sequence has a variable sup, I suppose?

Comment: You need to read the definitions. There are plenty of sources to do that. And come back here and post a question if you don't understand anything. You can't possibly hope to figure out what the term means with just the words, "lim" and "sup", no?

Answer (score 2):

If a sequence converges, its limit superior is equal to its  limit inferior and it is equal to its limit.

Comment: Not too useful, yet somewhat useful!